# Hive - counting distinct CSVs in one column

Tags: csv, hive

One of the **hive** tables looks something like this:

```
 ID    listOfcategories
    1     ["a","b","b","a","c","d","d"]
    2     ["a","a","a","c","c","c","c","e","e","e"]
    3     ["a","b","c"]
```

The number of comma-separated values is a variable. I want to query the number of distinct categories in each **row/ID.**
So, my output should look like:

```
ID     numDistCategories
1      4
2      3
3      3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` to [output separate rows for each category](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode) and then `count distinct` to get the result you are looking for.

Something like this.

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(cat)) as numDistCategories
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        EXPLODE(listOfcategories) AS cat 
    FROM myTable) a
GROUP BY id;
```

Hope that helps.